# Hide stdout of a process only when it is running in background

Tags: bash

How could I hide the standard output of a process only when it is running in background?

For example,

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 200); do
   echo $i
done
```

Now, I run the script. I stop it. I put it back to test it keeps running. Then I put it on background but it keeps printing in the standard output and I can't keep working. Is there a way to redirect or hide the process output ONLY when it is on background?

```
dione@saturno:~$ ./test.sh
1
2
3
^Z
[1]+  Detenido                ./test.sh
dione@saturno:~$ fg %1
./test.sh
4
5
6
^Z
[1]+  Detenido                ./test.sh
dione@saturno:~$ %1 &
[1]+ ./test.sh &
dione@saturno:~$ 7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
fg
./test.sh
16
17
^C
dione@saturno:~$
```

Comment: If it's possible, I don't think it will be easy: http://stackoverflow.com/q/593724/2072269

Comment: thanks muru for helping. it's not so easy I see! I run away from that post

Comment: I'll have to decide to redirect output to `/dev/null` from the start.

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting a running process's output is [not easy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/593724/2072269). But there might be alternatives if you work from the start:

```
some_long_runnning_command | tail -n 1000 & pkill -STOP tail
```

With this method, since the `tail` has `SIGSTOP` sent to it, it won't output anything until you explicitly bring it to the foreground using `fg` (or something similar) and until the script has finished. Adjust the `1000` to get as many lines as you want.

A better alternative might be `grep`:

```
some_long_runnning_command | grep . --color=never & pkill -STOP sed
```

You can signal `SIGCONT` and `SIGSTOP` to `grep` to start and stop the output as you want.

This can probably be combined with the re-attachment of open file descriptors from the SO question linked above (maybe with the script in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4066390/2072269)) so that this can be done with processes already opened.

---

If buffering is indeed a problem with `grep`, as [Volker Siegel points out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524960/hide-stdout-of-a-process-only-when-it-is-running-in-background/524964?noredirect=1#comment714839_524964), then one might consider using a more complex set of commands. First, note that [`sort`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sort.1.html) uses [temporary files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155954/70524), so buffering should not be a problem for it. It will act like a combination of `tail` and `grep` - waiting until the command is finished, like `tail`, and keeping the entire output, like `grep`. Something like:

```
some_long_runnning_command | awk '{$0=";"$0}1' | sort -k1.1,1.1 --stable | sed 's/^;//' & pkill -STOP sed
```

The loss here is that you can't start and stop the output at will, and there's the huge computation expended in an useless `sort`, as well as the work expended in adding and removing the `;`.

---

Further tests reveal that Volker is indeed correct:

For a script like (call it `test.sh`):

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1000000); do echo $i; echo $i > /tmp/log; done
```

and the command:

```
./test.sh | grep . --color=never & pkill -STOP grep
```

the number in `/tmp/log` was stuck at 12768 (with a similar figure for .
And with the command

```
./test.sh | awk '{$0=";"$0}1' | sort -k1.1,1.1 --stable | sed 's/^;//' & pkill -STOP sed
```

The script ran to completion (`/tmp/log` had `1000000`) without a peep from `sed`.

---

I still haven't managed to integrate this with the GDB method, but this as it is can be made to function as a function, similar to [John1024's](https://askubuntu.com/a/524967/158442). The problem is that you have no good way of knowing if the process has ended, since the shell only notifies you if the entire job has ended. So you'll have to use a checking function:

```
function check ()
{
    local PROC=${1:-$(jobs -p %%)}
    kill -0 $PROC 2>/dev/null && echo "The process is still running." || echo "The process is not running."
}

function bg ()
{

    "$@" | awk '{$0=";"$0}1' | sort -k1.1,1.1 --stable | sed 's/^;//' & 
    local PID=$!
    sleep 0.1s
    kill -STOP $PID
    cat <<EOF
To get the output, do: 
    kill -CONT $PID
To check if the process has finished, do:
    check $(jobs -p %%)
EOF
}
```

You could wrap the `"$@"` in another function which will notify you once the job is done, using something like `notify-send` or `write`.

It's been a nice exercise, but ultimately the simplest way is to redirect to `/dev/null` and forget the output: [How to redirect the output of an application in background to /dev/null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220098/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-an-application-in-background-to-dev-null).

Comment: I would think that, when  `grep .` is stopped, the command will fill the buffer of the pipe and will be stopped too?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel perhaps. But for the small outputs of my test script (`for i in {1..1000}; do echo $i; sleep 0.1s; done`) the command finished and only `grep` was waiting around.

Comment: Just tested with `seq 1000000 | grep . & pkill -STOP grep`, `seq` got stopped at 998.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel how did you get the `998` value?

Comment: Good question - the number was wrong. It was more like 18000; Obtained like this: When running `seq 1000000 | grep . & pkill -STOP grep` - the 998 was the last line shown (it varies by timing). Now, `pkill -STOP seq`, and `pkill -CONT grep` write the lines that already where in the buffer between `seq` and `grep`, which were about 17000 (18000 printed as last line minus about 1000 written out before grep stopped)

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret that. I think that's more an artifact of timing than of buffering. For example, a script with `for i in {1..1000000}; do echo $i; sleep 0.01s; done` (the same number as your command) finishes execution. How do I know this? When done, the shell updates after a command has been run, and `watch pstree -ps $(pgrep -f test.sh)`, where test.sh was the script, will show the entire process tree when the script is no longer in existence.

Comment: Hmm... 1000000 milliseconds are 166 minute, right? So you can not have tried that between posting the question and now?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel ah, I see now. I saw an error message that got quickly swept away: `fork: cannot allocate memory`. Also have a look at the update.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel although they are 166 minutes but sleep is set to 0.01s, that's why he could :D

Comment: @redraw Hmm... maybe I'm missing something, but: 1,000,000 iterations of 0.01 seconds each are take 1000000 * 0.01s = 10000 * 100 * 0.01s = 10000 * 1s = 10000s = 10000/60 minutes = 166.66... minutes, right?

Comment: oh, I thought you hadn't considered sleep 0.01, because you said "1000000 milliseconds are 166 minute", when you were actually saying "your 1000000 iterations represent 166 minutes"; so who gave me a vote right above? unvote it!

Comment: @redraw That was me, chuckling over the fact that neither of you have noticed my comment about my script erroring out.

Comment: anyway, I was discussing just a detail

Comment: @VolkerSiegel you were indeed right about the buffer problem.

Answer (score 1):

This script redirects stdout to `/dev/null` only if the script is running in the background:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$(ps -o stat= -p $$)" in
   *+*) : ;;
   *)  exec 1>/dev/null ;;
esac
for i in $(seq 200); do
   echo $i
done
```

The key here is that the `ps` `stat` field has a `+` in it when the job is foreground.  If the `+` is missing, we are in background.

If you want to keep stdout around for some things but not others, we can create a file descriptor 3 for the discretionary output and keep stdout active  for other output.
The script below implements this.  It sends the loop output to file descriptor 3.  File description 3 is either stdout if the job is running in the foreground or `/dev/null` if it is running in the background:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$(ps -o stat= -p $$)" in
   *+*) exec 3<&1 ;;
   *)  exec 3>/dev/null ;;
esac
for i in $(seq 200); do
  echo $i
done >&3
```

#### A Simple Way to Run Any Command in Background and Silently

Create this bash function:

```
bkg() { "$@" >/dev/null & }
```

Then, anytime that you want to a noisy command, say `seq 200`, in background, type:

```
bkg seq 200
```

The command will be run in background and its stdout will be disposed of.

To make the definition of `bkg` permanent, place the definition in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: clever way too! considering that way, it would only work with my scripts I suppose. actually, it's a pity that there's no included command on bash to do that with any process.

Comment: @redraw I updated the answer with a simple function that saves typing and handles putting a command, _any command_, in background and silencing its stdout.

Comment: John, do you mean a bash script? I'm not sure I can define a bash function for shell usage directly, or yes? by the way, it would be better to send the pid as argument, considering it is already running

Comment: Yes, bash functions are good for shell usage directly.  In a comment, you wrote "I'll have to decide to redirect output to /dev/null from the start."  This shell function was intended to make that easy to do.

Comment: Well, you're right. I was quiet disappointed when I said that, but that's a quick one to do that!