# run a process in background and give stdout for it even if terminal is closed

Tags: command-line, logging, stdout

I found some link here([Hide stdout of a process only when it is running in background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524960/hide-stdout-of-a-process-only-when-it-is-running-in-background)) about redirecting running process' output but my case(a module logging to stdout) is a bit different.

Cause I am using a module that logs to stdout. I can run the process in background and redirect output to some text file(the command I used: puma > console.txt). But so far I did not find any way to redirect that logging or leave a stdout to it(cause logging is still printed out on console, not to the file).

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. Could you rephrase your question so that what you are trying to accomplish and why becomes clear to us?
Because at the moment you state that you can redirect your program's output then go ahead and ask how to redirect the output.

Comment: Do you ask about redirection of stderr? It is achieved with `2> file`.

Comment: Well, sorry for the unclearance. Basically what I am saying is that I redirected stdout to console.txt but I still see some logging to stdout printed out. maybe it is stderr. i will try that first

Comment: @IncnisMrsi, yes turns out the module logs warning to stderr. thanks a lot for your help